# Searching a string having *

Tags: kdb

I have a table with symbols containing `*`.

```
q)sl:([] s:(`$"g*g";`$"b*l";`$"bx"))
q)sl
s
---
g*g
b*l
bx
```

How to escape the `*` (wild-card char) while searching, I want to search all the symbols containing `*` as a normal character ?

e.g. this one returns both rows containing 'b' , I just want it to return 'b*l'

```
q)select from sl where s like "b*"
s
---
b*l
bx
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using square brackets around the special character, as mentioned [here](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/regex/#special-characters).

So in this case:

```
q)select from sl where s like "b[*]*"
s  
---
b*l
```

Or to match anything with a `*` in it:

```
q)select from sl where s like "*[*]*"
s  
---
g*g
b*l
```